# Remove Border from HTML Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove borders (horizontal & vertical) lines both from the first row of the below snippet:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <br /><br /><br /><table id="myHeader" class="table  table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr style="border: none;">
            <td colspan="4" style="border: none;">
                <h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                <td><strong>400</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried the below code but no change was detected!

Tried:

```
<tr style="border: none;">
<td colspan="4" style="border: none;">
<h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
</td>
</tr>
```

I don't want any type of line (horizontal & vertical) to be displayed for the first row of the table. i.e: `Company` one.

Comment: have you tried `border="0"`?

Comment: There is no border on Company. There is border-top on Number making you think you have border on Company. Apply same css on Number and you 'll see the difference

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw tried but no result as wanted!

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I have updated the snippet, which will clear you that `company` also has borders..

Comment: @MKJ Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `@media print` rule to your stylesheet, and remove the border on both the `table` and first cell.

```css
body {
  /* for demo */
  margin: 20px !important;
}

#myHeader > tbody tr:first-of-type td {
  border-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#myHeader tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
  border-top: none;
}

@media print {
  table {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
  #myHeader tr:first-of-type td {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td><strong>400</strong></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @MKJ The top, left and right borders are on the table. Instead of removing these, you can change the border-color of the `tr td` to match the background color

Comment: The screenshot is taken when I give print command to the page, and still (after update) it has borders..

Comment: @MKJ Do you have a print stylesheet?

Comment: No, I don't have, in fact till now it was not needed, so I didn't include.

Comment: @MKJ I've updated again. I added `!important` to both rules and it works for me.

Comment: Somewhere, it helped but see the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/CsXy3)

Comment: @MKJ your HTML contains `tbody` after 4 `tr`. Either remove the `tbody` element (which I've done in my answer), or rework your HTML, add a `thead` etc

Comment: Ok, It worked! Thanks for helping. The `CSS` which you have the code, can I place them in different stylesheet naming `print.css` and add to the main page as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">` ?

Comment: @MKJ No problem, yes you can do that

Comment: If I get any problem while coding this (last touch), Can I trouble you once more that time?

Comment: @MKJ Sure, but better to ask a question I think

Comment: What is the role of `first-of-type` & if I would like to do the same thing with `number` then what to add in `@media print`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any border on company but you have `border` on table and number which is making border around company. Removing them will do the trick

```css
@media print {
  table {
    border: 0 !important;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br /><br /><br />
<table id="myHeader" class="table  table-bordered table-responsive" style="border:none;">
  <tr class="rem" style="border: none;">
    <td colspan="4" class="rem" style="border: none;">
      <h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="rem" style="border:none;">
      <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td><strong>400</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I get the details of changes (add/edit/delete) in codes you made?

Comment: added `style="border:none;"` on table tag and  on `td` containing number `<td colspan="4" style="border:none;">  <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1> </td>`. And do accept and upvote the answer if it helped

Comment: The screenshot I am providing, is the snippet you provide, by just giving a print command: https://imgur.com/a/Fc60z

Comment: @MKJ you sure??

Comment: Yes, you also try, `ctrl +p`

Comment: Any Update sir?

Comment: Need some time that looks like some other issue

Comment: Ok, No problem, thank you for investing time for me.

Comment: Thank you for investing time for me, I got the solution with https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163098/8835762, and if you get any other tricks please update your answer too with that, so that future readers and me too, get options to choose suitable code. (+1 to you too)

Comment: For future reference, your answer is displaying lines at the time of print!

Answer (score 0):

```
The border property was from the linked stylesheet. Updated your code by adding this - style="border:none !important" to both company and number.
Works fine now. But your code can be cleaner if you separate your css from your html.





    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <br /><br /><br /><table id="myHeader" class="table  table-bordered table-responsive">
            <tr style="border: none;">
                <td colspan="4" style="border:none !important" >
                    <h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="border:none !important" >
                    <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr.</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>400</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>




_____________________________________________
```

Updated Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <br /><br /><br /><table id="myHeader" class="table  table-bordered table-responsive" style="border-top:none !important; border-right:none !important; border-left:none !important">
        <tr style="">
            <td colspan="4" style="border:none !important" >
                <h1 class="text-center">Company</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="border:none !important; " >
                <h1 class="text-center">Number</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><span style="float: left;">Cutomer (Invoice No.)</span></h3>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><span style="float: right;">Date</span></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Shirt (D.C)</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Shirt (Iron)</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong>Four Hundred Rupees Only</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                <td><strong>400</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Run the snippet, Company has no borders.

Comment: Border above the company!Border beside the company!

Comment: Removed the border from the top, left and right of the table. This was responsible for the left and right borders.